# Strange behaviour when using createGraphics() with WEBGL in p5

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm working with p5.js and am experiencing strange behaviour when using the WebGL renderer in an offscreen graphics buffer.

Here is a simple example which draws a model on the canvas and scales it up to 101% size.
This works as expected. The model remains stationary each time the frame is re-drawn.

```
//working WEBGL createCanvas example

let icosa;

function preload() {
    icosa = loadModel('model.obj', true);
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 800, WEBGL);
}

function draw() { 
    background(0);
    //the model remains at 1.01 scale every time the frame is re-drawn, as expected.
    scale(1.01);

    model(icosa);
}
```

The strange behaviour happens when I render the webGL scene into a p5.Graphics offscreen graphics buffer using "createGraphics()".
I'm doing this to further process the rendered frames on a 2D canvas, shown here:

```
//broken WEBGL createGraphics example

let icosa;
let rend3d;

function preload() {
    icosa = loadModel('model.obj', true);
}

function setup() {
    rend3d = createGraphics(800, 800, WEBGL);
    createCanvas(800, 800);

}

function draw() { 
    rend3d.background(0);
    //the model continuously scales up every time the frame is re-drawn!
    rend3d.scale(1.01);
    rend3d.model(icosa);
    background(0);
    image(rend3d, 0,0, 800, 800);
}
```

Each time the frame is redrawn, the model continuously scales up. I'm not sure why this is happening, or what's causing it to behave differently than it does in my first example.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `draw` function has it's on `<main-canvas>.push()` and `<main-canvas>.pop()` on the backend so that transformations reset every time `draw()` is ran.

(the `<main-canvas>` is the placeholder that I'm calling it, it's definitely something different on the real backend of the p5js library, but that's thats what I'm calling it for simplicity.)

So you need to `push` and `pop` on the model's graphic object.

```js
function draw() { 
    rend3d.background(0);
    rend3d.push(); // Added line here
    rend3d.scale(1.01);
    rend3d.model(icosa);
    background(0);
    image(rend3d, 0,0, 800, 800);
    rend3d.pop(); // Added line here
}
```

Read more about `push()` [here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push) and `pop()` [here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pop)

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! I had tried something like this before, but was not assigning it to the graphic object correctly.